# How to pass parameters in API request to back-end URL with Azure APIM?

Tags: azure, api, parameters, azure-api-management

I'm trying to create a request with parameters in Azure API Management.

I have the following API(returns all invoices):

*www.apibackend.com/invoice*

This API can also handle parameters like this(returns invoice with ID 1):

*www.apibackend.com/invoice/1*

In my APIM service I've got the following code:

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <set-backend-service base-url="www.apibackend.com/" />
    <rewrite-uri template="/invoice" />
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```

With the APIM URL(for example: www.apim.com/test/GetInvoices) I can make the following request to my backend:

*www.apibackend.com/invoice*

This will return all the invoices, but how do I only retrieve the invoice with ID 1? If i make the request "www.apim.com/test/GetInvoices/1" I will get an error.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual question is. how to pass in query string to the backend api?

Comment: I want to send a parameter with the front-end string of Azure API Management to my back-end API.

Comment: well, depends on how you get it? calculate it and send it over

Answer (score 0):

In APIM change your Operation template to `GetInvoices/{id}` then in policies you'll be able to do:

```
<rewrite-uri template="/invoice/{id}" />
```